# How to automatically put text into picture files

Tags: gimp, image-processing, batch

I have a template for a business card and a text file with several hundred codes (each separated by commas). Is there a method to (automatically): for each code overlay it onto the template and export an image?

Note: I'm hoping to achieve results similar to this: http://uk.moo.com/ideas/perch.html.

Comment: I haven't time for a complete answer now, but you can write a script that uses imagemagick. I will try to post a complete answer later (if I don't forget it).

Comment: You may be able to achieve this with LibreOffice and 'mail merge', however you will need to convert the file so that every code is on its own line.

Comment: @Javier If you could explain how to use, and do this, in ImageMagick that would be fantastic!

Comment: @aquaherd My image template is a PNG file so I don't think Libre Office can open/edit it very well (though I could well be wrong!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gLabels](http://glabels.org/) [image: install glabels] is a very useful & powerful program to do such things, although normally it will print and not create new images.  (You might have to reformat the text file into a CSV file or something like that, but that should be easy enough—if not, ask how to do it in another question on this site...)

Alternatively, LibreOffice should be able to do something similar too.

If you really want to make hundreds of images, you could probably use ImageMagic.

Comment: gLabels appears to put things (like business cards) into a printable format, so 12+ per A4 sheet. I need it to export one file per code. Though I could be wrong!

Comment: As you probably figured out by now: you can use the "mail merge" features to make each business card unique.